# Tig: how to view project from first commit?

Tags: git, tig

Just want to checkout first commit quickly.

Now tig sort the commits as latest commit as the first, so it's quite difficult to find first commit and check the project's evaluation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To see the oldest commit first pass `--reverse`, e.g.

```
tig --reverse
```

Answer (score 4):

I found answer.

Use `End` to jump to last line and get the first commit.

For OS X, `fn` + `→`.